"No Bootable Device" error messages

This is a very old computer (~20yo Gateway). Previously I have had various versions of Ubuntu running on it just fine.

I had Ubuntu 20.04 running fine on this machine until I erased the drive and intalled 24.04 from a USB with belenaEtcher.

After installing I started getting "No Bootable Device" error messages.

I ran Seagate SeaTools, and the drive passes all the tests.

This is NOT a dual boot. Only Ubuntu installed.

I checked using Live Ubuntu, and Ubuntu is installed on the drive.

I ran Boot Repair, but I am still getting the error message.

I installed Mint from a DVD. Same error. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 from a DVD. Same error.

I have looked through the BIOS and I don't see any obvious problems, or solutions. I do not see UEFI or CSM (old computer).


UPDATES:
I used gparted. I tried the flags: boot, legacy_boot, bls_boot, and bios-grub. But I am still getting "No Bootable Device" error messages.
EDIT:
I started with Ubuntu 20.04 running, I installed 24.04 with error, I installed 22.04 with error.
WORKAROUND:
I just installed 20.04 and it is booting. I used Software Updater to install 22.04 and it is booting.

If the drive also 20 years old? If so if may be failing.

Boot from install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode. Run gparted. Ensure that the disk partition where grub resides has the BOOT flag set.

Whatever is wrong with your system it doesn't seem to be an Ubuntu software issue.

I checked the drive with Seagate SeaTools. And I used a Live version to confirm that Ubuntu is installed on the drive.
Also, Live Ubuntu runs, so CPU and memory are working. I am not sure what hardware would be causing this problem.

@waltinator    Thank you, I didn't know about gparted. I have tried the flags: boot, legacy_boot, bls_boot, and bios-grub. But I am still getting "No Bootable Device" error messages.

Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

It's not a drive problem. Everyone is having this problem. Something to do with uefi and secure boot.
Leave it to linux to screw things up.
Found my wifi and was looking great until this problem.
If I go to the boot menu every time it boots.
Just not automatic after power down or even restart.
